# How to reverse array key without affecting the values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `array(1=>'randstring1', 2=>'randstring2', 3=>'randstring3', 4=> 'randstring4')` I want to reverse or sort the key from 4 to 1 while preserving the value so it would be like

```
Array(
   [4] => randstring1
   [3] => randstring2
   [2] => randstring3
   [1] => randstring4
)
```

Comment: @jh1711 a simple array reverse doesn't preserve the values but will reverse both keys and values I only want to reverse the keys not values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) should do the trick.

```
$newArray = array_combine( array_reverse( array_keys( $array ) ), $array );
```

Comment: Nice solution !